# VS Code can't detect .NET Core SDK

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I've been getting this error for the last 3 days, I've already tried to reinstall VS Code and the .NET Core SDK, but nothing worked.

[image: Here is th error]

Comment: Exec `dotnet --info`